# login screen + Table view Controller + core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a login screen and when the user enters the login and password and hits the done button, it should take it to the next view (information entered by the user).

Now, I have two entities: Login and Information.

For the login screen, my code snippet in prepare for segue method is:

```
    NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Login" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid==%@ AND password==%@",_loginTextfield.text, _passwordTextField.text];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *anyError=Nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&anyError];
    if([fetchedObjects count] )
    {
        InformationTVC *informationTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        informationTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    }
    else
    {
        return;            

    }
```

How to pass the entered user id and password and make that true for the entire session.

In my next view, when I am checking the login id and password it is showing all the logins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix up your question a bit.

"How to pass the entered user id and password and make that true for
the entire session"

It seems like you think that an id and password are Boolean?

If you have a view that you just want add to the scene you can say something simple like:

```
[self.view addSubview: viewInformation];
[viewInformation setCenter:CGPointMake(160,230)];
```

And when you want to remove that view you can do something like:

```
[viewInformation removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Looks like u have misunderstood my question. I have 2 entities:  Login(userid,password) and Information(title,info). When a user enters userid and password and submits the done button, the view should display information.title related to only that userid. So how to propogate the userid entered by user

Comment: Why would you ever get a user to enter a userid? and if you what to get the userID just do a SELECT statement on the server like:  SELECT id WHERE username = '$Username'     this is php by the way which you use in combination with obective c in the app to do this.